# Travelling to Japan from Korea on a UK passport

Tags: visas, japan, passports, south-korea, asia

I have a UK passport and an E2 Visa for living and working in Korea. Will I encounter any difficulties if I want to travel to Japan, or will I need to get a visa when I get there or before I go (i.e. here in Korea)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a UK citizen you [do not need a visa for Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens). The fact that you have a E2 Korean visa does not influence that at all.